# pandas - Counting occurrences of a value in a DataFrame per each unique value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

Supposing that I have a DataFrame along the lines of:

```py
    term      score
0   this          0
1   that          1
2   the other     3
3   something     2
4   anything      1
5   the other     2
6   that          2
7   this          0
8   something     1
```

How would I go about counting up the instances in the `score` column by unique values in the `term` column? Producing a result like:

```py
    term      score 0     score 1     score 2     score 3
0   this            2           0           0           0
1   that            0           1           1           0
2   the other       0           0           1           1
3   something       0           1           1           0
4   anything        0           1           0           0
```

Related questions I've read here include [Python Pandas counting and summing specific conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995196/python-pandas-counting-and-summing-specific-conditions) and [COUNTIF in pandas python over multiple columns with multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24810526/countif-in-pandas-python-over-multiple-columns-with-multiple-conditions), but neither seems to quite be what I'm looking to do. `pivot_table` as mentioned at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37203156/finding-intersection-of-values-in-a-column-associated-with-unique-values-in-anot) seems like it could be relevant but I'm impeded by lack of experience and the brevity of the pandas documentation. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47152692/2336654

Comment: That's a really useful resource, thank you.

Comment: You are welcome (-:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html), last [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['term','score']).size().unstack(fill_value=0).add_prefix('score ')
```

Or use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df = pd.crosstab(df['term'],df['score']).add_prefix('score ')
```

Or [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
df = (df.pivot_table(index='term',columns='score', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)
        .add_prefix('score '))
```

---

```
print (df)
score      score 0  score 1  score 2  score 3
term                                         
anything         0        1        0        0
something        0        1        1        0
that             0        1        1        0
the other        0        0        1        1
this             2        0        0        0
```

Comment: I was about to post the crosstab, then you edited. Then I was like, oh pivot! And you edited :D. Nice answer

Comment: I think `crosstab` is my favorite of the options here - succinct and simple. Thanks also for the range of methods - a lot to learn.

Comment: @jezrael Where you've suggested `aggfunc='size'`, what is `'size'`? The examples in the docs show functions being passed in unquoted, like `aggfunc=np.sum`.

Comment: @ScottMartin - This function is same like [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html)

Comment: I see - part of the [GroupBy computations / descriptive stats function group](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#id39). Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use, `get_dummies`, `set_index`, and `sum` with `level` parameter:

```
(pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('term'), columns=['score'], prefix_sep=' ')
   .sum(level=0)
   .reset_index())
```

Output:

```
        term  score 0  score 1  score 2  score 3
0       this        2        0        0        0
1       that        0        1        1        0
2  the other        0        0        1        1
3  something        0        1        1        0
4   anything        0        1        0        0
```

Comment: Thank you, `get_dummies` is something I've been meaning to learn more about using and this will help with that.